Invalid column name al intentar obtener ranking en sql
Tengo el siguiente query sql y deseo conocer cuáles son los 3 service más utilizados por cada customer, mostrando de mayor a menor los service más utilizados por el customer, así como la cantidad de veces que utilizo el service:
WITH cte_customer_usage AS (
  SELECT
    customer,
    service,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY service DESC) AS usage_count,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY usage_count DESC) AS usage_rank
  FROM total_service
  GROUP BY customer, service
)
SELECT
  cte_customer_usage.customer,
  cte_customer_usage.service,
  cte_customer_usage.usage_count
FROM cte_customer_usage
WHERE usage_rank <= 3
ORDER BY customer, usage_rank DESC

pero me da el siguiente error:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'usage_count'.


¿Intentaste darle un alias al CTE en la consulta, o evitar anteponer el nombre del CTE en las columnas en el SELECT? Además, pon en las etiquetas qué gestor de bases de datos estás utilizando (SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL...)

El problema es que no puedes referenciar un alias dentro de una misma lista de columnas. Puedes usar el cte en cascada para poder referenciarlo.
WITH cte_customer_usage AS (
  SELECT
    customer,
    service,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY service DESC) AS usage_count
  FROM total_service
  GROUP BY customer, service
),
cte_customer_usage_rank AS(
  SELECT
    cu.customer,
    cu.service,
    cu.usage_count,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY usage_count DESC) AS usage_rank
  FROM cte_customer_usage AS cu
)
SELECT
  cur.customer,
  cur.service,
  cur.usage_count
FROM cte_customer_usage_rank AS cur
WHERE usage_rank <= 3
ORDER BY customer, usage_rank DESC;


El problema es que en la cláusula select no hay ningún orden. Tienes la impresión que primero haces esto
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY service DESC) AS usage_count

así creando el nombre usage_count para el count, y entonces
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY usage_count DESC) AS usage_rank

usando el nombre. Pero no es así. Estas líneas deben ser independientes, para que el DBMS puede elegir cual expresión calcular primero y cual segundo. No puedes usar un alias que estas creando en la misma cláusula.
Además usas COUNT OVER. Hay una fila por customer y service en el resultado. Con
 COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY service DESC)

para cada customer el ultimo service en el alfabeto recibe el count 1, el penúltimo 2, etc.
Lo que quieres es un simple COUNT.
Entonces:
WITH cte_customer_usage AS 
(
  SELECT
    customer,
    service,
    COUNT(*) AS usage_count,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS usage_rank
  FROM total_service
  GROUP BY customer, service
)
...

Y quizás quieres DENSE_RANK o RANK en vez de ROW_NUMBER.
